# JavaScript getting window height is wrong on site refresh

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to find out wether the site is scrollable or not.

Currently I'm comparing `$("body").height()` and `window.innerHeight`.

As long as the user opens it with the url or with a link it's all fine, I'm getting the height of the whole site. But if I'm already on this page and just press F5 this `$("body").height()` returns the height of the window and no longer of the whole page (I can still scroll).

I already tried `$(window).height()` and `document.documentElement.clientHeight` as well. All three methods are always returning the same. (Right value if with url or link, wrong if F5 or Ctrl+ R).

Somebody know where my mistake is or is there another method i could use?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: For clarification: I have a footer bar, which should always be on the bottom of the current page. If the page is scrollable, the div with the footer shows up in the end of the page. If not, im setting the main div too 100%, so the footer shows up in the bottom. I'm checking it currently that way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (document.body.scrollHeight == document.body.clientHeight) {
    document.getElementById("mainbody").style = "height: 100%";
  }
});
```

And my body is like this:

```
<body>
  <div class="mainbody" id="mainbody">
    <?php include "assets/header.php" ?>
    <?php include $currentsite ?>
    <?php include "assets/footer.php" ?>
  </div>
</body>
```

The div with the footer has `width: 100%; bottom: 0; position: absolute;`. But if you just reload the page scrollHeight, clientHeight, innerHeight and height() are all returningthe height of thr screen and no longer of the actual document. I hope that more understandable. And sorry for my bad english.

Here's the problem visualized: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pzWHUsE0ozA

Comment: Some of your code would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try comparing `scrollHeight` and `clientHeight`. Like so:

```
if (document.body.scrollHeight !== document.body.clientHeight){
    // Scrollable
} else{
    // Not scrollable
}
```

Comment: It's still the same problem with your example D:

Comment: Could you add a Fiddle with your code? Or any link?

Comment: The site is https://timpa.dev/?p=pictures
If you open it normall or with the link in the header its all good, if you press F5 or Ctrl+R the footer is wrong.

Comment: Its exactlly what im trying to explain. And neither your nor my methods are working correctly

Comment: I got confused by another question I was dealing with. I'll take a look at it now.

Comment: `document.body.clientHeight` is giving me a lower value than `document.body.scrollHeight`. That means the page is scrollable. Isn't that what you wanted to know?

Comment: I made a video with the problem, maybe i missexplained what the exactly i meant: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pzWHUsE0ozA

Comment: I know what you mean, but looks like I'm unable to reproduce this error. Also made a video, check it [here](https://streamable.com/yjjhg)

Comment: Try with another browser i.e. Chrome